# How to make Moq mock object has the effect of IEqualityComparer of the actual class

Tags: linq, f#, moq

I have a class implementing `IEqualityComparer` for custom equality test

When I use `Mock.Of` to mock some objects and put them in 2 lists to use `Linq.Except` on them. The result, which is the difference of these lists, is all the objects. This means that the custom EqualityComparer was not used

When I manually create SomeClass object, `Linq.Except` works and the diff result is empty

My question is: how can I make Mock object behave like the actual object in `Linq.Except`? I feel like this is a bug of Moq

Thank you for your help!

```
[<Test>]
let ``similar object should diff to none`` () =
    let list1 = createMockList ()
    let list2 = createMockList ()

    let diff = list1.Except list2

    Assert.That(diff, Is.Empty, "similar lists should diff to zero")

let createMockList (): SomeClass array =

    let sr1 = Mock.Of<SomeClass>(
        fun (o: SomeClass ) ->
            o.Account = "hello"
    )
    let sr2 = Mock.Of<SomeClass>(
        fun (o: SomeClass ) ->
            o.Account = "world"
    )
    let sr3 = Mock.Of<SentinelRow>(
        fun (o: SomeClass ) ->
            o.Account = "bye"
    ) 
    
    [|sr1;sr2;sr3|]

let thisWillWork (): SomeClass array =

    let sr1 = new SomeClass()
    sr1.Account <- "Hello"

    let sr2 = new SomeClass()
    sr2.Account <- "world"
    
    let sr3 = new SomeClass()
    sr3.Account <- "bye"

    [|sr1;sr2;sr3|]
```

Comment: What is the definition of SomeClass?

Comment: for simplicity, you can assume it only has 1 property string Account, and implements the IEquatableComparer to override the Equal method.

Comment: Not familiar with `Mock.Of`, but I wonder if
`fun (o: SomeClass ) ->o.Account = "hello"`
is doing what you expect it does. `o.Account = "hello"` will not set the property, it should evaluate to false. Perhaps try `o.Account <- "hello"; o`